# How to write a function using a loop which finds the range (dif between high and low) of array of numbers. Must return arr with low, high and range

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve question below:

> "Using a loop, write a function getTheRange which finds the range (difference between high and low) of arr. The value returned should be an array with the low, high, and range."

My Code is Below:

```
const getTheRange = arr => {
  const newArray = []
  let range = 0

  const low = Math.min(...arr);
    newArray.push(low)

  const high = Math.max(...arr);
    newArray.push(high)

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     range = high-low;
     newArray.push(range)
   }

   return newArray;
}

console.log(getTheRange([3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 9, 10])); // expect log [2, 10, 8]
```

I do get my low min and range values ([2, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]), problem is that my range keeps repeating. My guess is due to the loop. But I honestly ran out of ideas on how to stop it from repeating. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The range is a single number. Don't loop - just push it and you're done. `newArray.push(high - low);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question hope you find high & low by loop, instead of min() or max().

```js
const getTheRange = (arr) => {
  let low = arr[0],
    high = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < low) {
      low = arr[i];
    } else {
      high = arr[i];
    }
  }
  let range = high - low;
  return [low, high, range];
};

console.log(getTheRange([3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 9, 10]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTheRange(arr) {
  const low = Math.min(...arr);
  const high = Math.max(...arr);
  let range = high-low;
  return [low,high,range];
}
```

Comment: Add something more to your answer than just a code snippet to explain what you want to add to the topic or how your answer differs from the others.